# Changing the Open Atrium 2 login hyperlink

Tags: distributions

How do I change the open atrium 2 login hyperlink for anonymous users so that they can register instead of being directed to the user login page?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Goto admin/config/people/accounts
- Select **Registration and cancellation**
- Under **Who can register accounts?**, chose **Visitors** instead of **Administrators only**

Then users can create an account from the user/login page.